# SQL Dynamic columns based on rows from join

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, join

I've been working couple of months on preparing SQL views and I was wondering if there is a way to automate a process a little.

For each type of task we can have different number of custom fields in the database, which are stored in different table. And there is third table, which connects task with those custom fields.

Table 1 - Task

| ID | Number | ...

Table 2 - Relationship with custom fields

| Task_ID | Custom_Field_ID

Table 3 - Custom fields values

| ID | Value | Name

I would like to generate view where I can have all custom fields in one row together with values from the task, I can achieve that manually joining those tables for each custom field separately, but I was wondering if I could do that in one loop, so it can be dynamic for unlimited number of custom fields.

eg.

| ID | Number | Custom_Field_1.value | Custom_Field_2.value | ...

```
select task.id, task.number, (some loop here ?? )
from task
left join relationship
inner join custom_field
on custom_field.id = relationship.custom_field_id
on relationship.task_id = task.id
```

For now those last 4 lines I need to replicate manually for each custom field, but maybe it can be done via some loop.

Does anyone have suggestions? Is this even doable? I can't change the structure of the database.

Comment: Sounds like you have some kind of EAV design. You won't be able to use a `VIEW` to "normalise" these as the columns will either need to be hardcoded, and so not reflect new attributes, or you'll need dynamic SQL, and a `VIEW` must have a well defined static definition.

Comment: You could build your view(s) dynamically by using the ouput from `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set()`